# PageMethods.set_path does not work in urlrewriting

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, webmethod, pagemethods

I have a test web application that calls a single PageMethod via Javascript function.

```
PageMethods.myMethod(params, onSuccess, onFailed);
```

When i use urlRewriting it doesn't work anymore. So, i searched web and i found this to add to js file.

```
Pagemethods.set_path("/the_real_path.aspx");
```

However this does not work. It gives an 404 not found error when i looked web developer tool in chrome with F12.

Is there any advice you can give ? Any help would appreciated

Below are done.

```
-ScriptManager EnablePageMethods = True
-Method is public and shared(static)
-Method is decorated with <WebMethod(True)>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Anyway, I found another way to call the `WebMethod`. I used Webservice. I don't need to use PageMethods.